# Polymer Component not independent from each other?

Tags: polymer

Given this simplified component:

```
<dom-module id="poly-component">
<template>
    <paper-button raised onclick="dialog.open()">Button</paper-button>
    <paper-dialog id="dialog"><h1>Paper Dialog Here!</h1></paper-dialog>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'poly-component'
    })
</script>
```

which does nothing more than open the dialog on clicking the button.
This module works when it used once on a page.
But when it is inserted twice

```
[...]
<dom-module id="polyTest-app">
    <template>
        <h2>Hello [[prop1]]</h2>
        <poly-component></poly-component>
        <poly-component></poly-component>
    </template>
[...]
```

it doesn't work anymore.
A click on the button leads to a:

```
(index):1 Uncaught TypeError: dialog.open is not a function
```

Am I missing something?

The code for this example can be found here: [Example Code on GitHub](https://github.com/mafulafunk/polyTestNotAFunction)

Comment: By the way, are you saying that single instance of `<poly-component>` works fine?

Comment: Yes it does! I found that right in the demo code of <paper-dialog>: https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog/blob/master/demo/index.html

Comment: Please see the update to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code cannot work because you're not binding the event handler correctly.

A built-in handler like `onclick` tries to execute the bit of code in global scope where `dialog` doesn't exist. Hence the error.

Here's how you can rewrite your code

```
<dom-module id="poly-component">
  <template>
    <paper-button raised on-click="_dialogOpen">Button</paper-button>
    <paper-dialog id="dialog"><h1>Paper Dialog Here!</h1></paper-dialog>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'poly-component',
        _dialogOpen: function() {
          this.$.dialog.open();
        }
    })
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

First, notice how `onclick` changes to `on-click` - the Polymer [event handling notation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#annotated-listeners). PS. `tap` event is advised.

Second, you can only access other elements from code. Not directly in bindings. Hence the `_dialogOpen` function.

**UPDATE**

Ok, I know what's happening. When there is only one element with a given `id`, the browsers let's you use it simply by that id in global scope.

When you use Shady DOM, which I assume you do, two instances of your `poly-component` element render two `<dialog id="dialog">`. At this point `window.dialog` is not available anymore.

Again, with Polymer it's safer to use the `this.$` notation aka [Automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding) to reference elements in local DOM.